# Nautilus launches from command, but gives error not seen yesterday

Tags: nautilus, malware

In terminal I launched nautilus and got this error:

Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)

Why today? I made no changes and this didn't happen yesterday?! It persists through a restart.

Is this sudden change in behavior indicative of a virus??

Comment: Perhaps similar to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/798928/nautilus-share-message-called-net-usershare-info-but-it-failed

Comment: Similar, yes. In that post never was the question answered about why Nautilus suddenly decided to need that file but didn't need it before.